# Writing an Camel Exchange property to the HTTP Header

Tags: spring, http, apache-camel

I am having a Camel route with several steps configured in Spring XML. After the last step I want to set the a header entry Content-Type using a value from the Exchange properties. How can I achieve that?

```
<route id="servlet.direct">        
    <from uri="direct:onlinePlatformExport"/>
    <bean ref="exportService" method="doSomething"/>
    <to uri="smooks://META-INF/spring/a.xml"/>                
    <bean ref="charsetConverterService" method="convertBody"/>
    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
       <constant>text/xml</constant>
    </setHeader>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. You can access the exchange object using Groovy.

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
   <groovy>"text/xml; charset=${exchange.properties[<your-key>]}"</groovy>
</setHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following:

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <simple>${property.myProperty}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: Good to know. This works when I want to pass the whole value of a property to the header. If I want to create a new value containing the properties value do I have to use <groovy> or can I still use <simple>?

Comment: `<simple/>` can be used even in the following form: `<simple>text text ${<some instruction>} text text</simple>`. But be careful about special characters. I believe that the following thing will work as expected `<simple>text/xml; charset=${property.myProperty}</simple>`